# Listviews child Textviews typeface error

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

When i change the type face of all textviews on the current activity  all change except for 
the  Textview Text.

But when i call the same function from the itemclick listener  of listview the font changes

```
        ((TextView) view).setTypeface(CreateTypeface);
```

How can i set the font of listview without having to click it?

```
     final View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);


public  void applyCustomFont(ViewGroup list) 
    {


         for (int i = 0; i < list.getChildCount(); i++) {
             View view = list.getChildAt(i);

             if (view instanceof ViewGroup) 
             {
                 applyCustomFont((ViewGroup) view);
             } else if (view instanceof TextView) 
             {
                 ((TextView) view).setTypeface(CreateTypeface);



         }
        }
     }



     lvfonts.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (FontMUI.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));

     lvfonts.setOnItemClickListener(new  OnItemClickListener() 
     { 

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3)
                  {
                   applyCustomFont((ViewGroup)rootView);
                        }
                        }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear..My understanding is that set the typeface in getview of adpater class..

Comment: @Subburaj  i have not used getview method i have updated my code check

Comment: In click part of listview you called "Customfont()" method.then only when clicking listview item it will call and font  will change..This is the output of your code..Whats your question??

Comment: @Subburaj i have not pasted the whole code i have called the function in oncreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this trick to set typeface of a listview Since listview is not a subclass of Textview the childs of listview would cannot be accessed directly you need to access them through the listview itself.

```
lvfonts.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                applyCustomFont((ViewGroup)rootView);
                 // or call you function to change the Typeface from here 
            }
            }, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a custom Adapter that you use to populate the ListView.  In that custom Adapter, you will need to override the `getView()` method to make any changes you want to the View(s) before they are displayed to the user.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        ((TextView) convertView).setTypeface(CreateTypeface);
    }

    setupTextForPosition(convertView, position);
}
```